# Notification when Windows enters in sleep mode

Tags: winapi

Is there any way to find out when Windows will enter sleep mode/is in sleep mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using managed code then this is exposed in the `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event.

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;

private void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend) {
    // Going to sleep
  }
}
```

If you're using native code then you want to listen for the `WM_POWERBROADCAST` message in your `WindowProc` handler.

```
LRESULT WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  if (WM_POWERBROADCAST == message && PBT_APMSUSPEND == wParam) {
    // Going to sleep
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it in your edit. I was posting this after your first answer just mentioned managed code. :) +1 and deleting my answer.